# Angular2 testing: What's the difference between a DebugElement and a NativeElement object in a ComponentFixture?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, angular, jasmine

I'm currently putting together some best practices for testing Angular 2 apps on a component level.

I've seen a few tutorials query a fixture's NativeElement object for selectors and the like, e.g.

```html
it('should render "Hello World!" after click', async(() => {
    builder.createAsync(HelloWorld).then((fixture: ComponentFixture<HelloWorld>) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let el = fixture.nativeElement;
        el.querySelector('h1').click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
            
        expect(el.querySelector('h1')).toHaveText('Hello World!');
    });
}));
```

However, in [juliemr's Angular 2 test seed](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed/blob/master/src/test/border-component_test.ts) she accesses the NativeElement through a parent DebugElement object.

```html
it('should render "Hello World!" after click', async(() => {
    builder.createAsync(HelloWorld).then((fixture: ComponentFixture<HelloWorld>) => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      compiled.querySelector('h1').click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
            
      expect(compiled.querySelector('h1')).toHaveText('Hello World!');
    });
}));
```

Are there any specific cases you'd use a fixture's debugElement.nativeElement over its nativeElement?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

- `nativeElement` returns a reference to the DOM element
- `DebugElement` is an Angular2 class that contains all kinds of references and methods relevant to investigate an element or component (See the [source of DebugNode and DebugElement](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/core/src/debug/debug_node.ts)

Comment: Cheers - so  I guess if I'm not using any of DebugElement's members except nativeElement it's probably more readable to just go with componentFixture.nativeElement then.

Comment: `nativeElement` only helps you when you want to investigate the DOM (are attributes, classes, ... set or cleared or maybe dispatch DOM events). When you want to investigate the state of parts of the Angular2 application (components, directives, ...) then you need `DebugElement`

Answer (score 37):

to add on to what has been mentioned already :

```
  abstract class ComponentFixture {
  debugElement;       // test helper 
  componentInstance;  // access properties and methods
  nativeElement;      // access DOM
  detectChanges();    // trigger component change detection
}
```

source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a7e9bc97f6a19a2b47b962bd021cb91346a44baa/modules/angular2/src/testing/test_component_builder.ts#L31

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at [Angular discussion about this topic](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5385) and related [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5513/files).

Mainly:

```
fixture.componentInstance == fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
fixture.nativeElement == fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
```

Comment: Cheers, very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

`.nativeElement()` returns DOM tree whereas `debugElement` returns a JS object (debugElement tree). `debugElement` is a Angular's method.

`.nativeElement()` is Browser specific API that returns or give access to DOM tree. But what if application is running on non-browser platform (such as server or web-worker), in that case `.nativeElement()` may throw error.

> If we are sure that our application will run on browser only, then
>   unhesitantly we can use `let el = fixture.nativeElement`. But if we
>   are not sure about the platform then to be on safer side use `let le =
>   fixture.debugElement` because it returns a plain JS Object.