# Diff between DebugElement and DOM element

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In angular unit testing using jasmine, we can test the view (html content) in two ways.

1. Getting the elements from DebugElement

   `fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.tableData.billStatus.text-center'))`
2. Getting the elements from DOM.

   `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.tableData.billStatus.text-center')`

My question is not related to `queryAll` vs `querySelectorAll`. It is `DOM` vs `DebugElement`. Because when I use either of them, they give me the correct result most of the time.

This question has some relation to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13066#issuecomment-395155562)

They give a work around to look through `DOM` elements as opposed to `DebugElement` as a work around. So what makes these two differ from each other?

I have looked through several posts for the difference, before making this question. But I did not find anything appropriate to this.

Comment: fixture.debugElement.querySelectorAll('.tableData.billStatus.text-center').nativeElement you mean this right?

Comment: Have you check this link?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705599/angular2-testing-whats-the-difference-between-a-debugelement-and-a-nativeeleme/37707781

Comment: @NarendraSolanki Yes, I had seen that post, but question is How DebugElement is related to DOM. If DebugElement is an angular class, should not that be internally refereing DOM elements. If so, then why does it give different results?

Answer (score 0):

`debug element` contains references and methods to a component or element whereas `native element` is a reference to the DOM element.

Comment: Can you elaborate it more? My question was not about nativeElement definition. It is about relation or the diff between Debug Element and DOM.

Comment: when i say DOM i mean you would be able to see styles, classes, innerHTML attributes etc etc on native element. However when i say component reference , you would only e able to see properties such as injectors! hope i could clear that!!

Answer (score 0):

The Usage of DebugElement vs NativeElement depends on your scenario:

- If you are going to run your tests only on the browser, then NativeElement is enough, since the tests will be run on the browser, the DOM will be available for NativeElement to do its operations.
- If you are going to run your tests on server or some pipeline where the browser platform is not available, then you should use DebugElement, as it will wrap the native elements of the runtime platform, so that you can do query on non-browser supported platforms too.