# Jasmin Angular : Checkbox select unselect not working as expected

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ionic4

```
    it('Reset filter works properly', () => {
     fixture.detectChanges();
     fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const hostElement = fixture.nativeElement;
        const checkBox: HTMLInputElement = hostElement.querySelector('#filter ion-item:first-child ion-checkbox');
        console.log('checkBox', checkBox);
        expect(checkBox.checked).toBe(false);
        checkBox.click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(checkBox.checked).toBe(true);
```

trying unit testing the basic checkbox functionality in angular 9, Jasim framework

Here initially checkbox will be unchecked, then selecting it with a click, But not working as expected.

> console.log prints checkbox element

```
<ion-checkbox _ngcontent-a-c154="" color="selection" mode="md" slot="start" class="ion-margin-start"></ion-checkbox>
```

Error message
     **Error: Expected undefined to be false.**

Answer (score 1):

You should access the checkbox with the debugElement. It contains all kinds of references and methods relevant to investigating an element or component. [DebugElement vs NativeElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37705853/1934484)

```js
const checkBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#filter ion-item:first-child ion-checkbox')).nativeElement;
```

Boolean test the checkbox

```js
expect(checkBox.checked).toBeFalsy();

checkBox.click();
fixture.detectChanges();

expect(checkBox.checked).toBeTruthy();
```